# Can I get rid of xmlns tags (and maybe also resources) from my all user controls by using style/resource?

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-4.8

I would like to get rid of `xmlns` tags from every `UserControl` or `Window` file.

Can I do it by using styles or resources somehow?

Many of my user controls look like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Mst2.View.Controls.Modules.TimerEntryControl"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:bcp="clr-namespace:ABitOfBinding"
             xmlns:dc="clr-namespace:Mst2.Dictionaries"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Mst2.ViewModel"
             xmlns:vc="clr-namespace:Mst2.ValueConverters"
             xmlns:c="clr-namespace:Mst2.View.Controls"
             xmlns:mw="clr-namespace:Mst2.View.Windows"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <dc:Mst2Dictionaries x:Key="Dictionaries" />
        <bcp:ByteBit2Bool x:Key="ByteBit2Bool" />
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis" />
        <vc:TimerTimeAndRangeConverter x:Key="TimerTimeAndRangeConverter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <!-- user control contents here -->

</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you instantiate resources from a specific namespace, it has to be declared. How would the parser know which type you are referring to? However, if these resources are located in a **separate assembly**,  you can create a custom XAML namespace and map all of your CLR namespaces to it. This does not work if the resources and namespaces are defined in the same assembly.

- [Mapping CLR Namespaces to XML Namespaces in an Assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/xaml-namespaces-and-namespace-mapping-for-wpf-xaml?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#mapping-clr-namespaces-to-xml-namespaces-in-an-assembly)

Add an [`XmlnsDefinition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.xmlnsdefinitionattribute?view=net-5.0) attribute for each CLR namespace with your desired XML namespace.

> Specifies a mapping on a per-assembly basis between a XAML namespace and a CLR namespace, which is then used for type resolution by a XAML object writer or XAML schema context.

> The `XmlnsDefinitionAttribute` takes two parameters: the XML/XAML namespace name, and the CLR namespace name. More than one `XmlnsDefinitionAttribute` can exist to map multiple CLR namespaces to the same XML namespace.

You need to insert the attribute at assembly level, so you have to own or be able to modify it.

> This attribute, `XmlnsDefinitionAttribute`, is placed at the assembly level in the source code that produces the assembly.

For example for your `Mst2` assembly, the attributes in `AssemblyInfo.cs` could look like below. You are free to choose the URI, it does not have a special meaning here beyond being an identifer.

```
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.Mst2.com/2021", "Mst2.Dictionaries")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.Mst2.com/2021", "Mst2.ViewModel")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.Mst2.com/2021", "Mst2.ValueConverters")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.Mst2.com/2021", "Mst2.View.Controls")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.Mst2.com/2021", "Mst2.View.Windows")]
```

Additionally, you could define an [`XmlPrefix`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.xmlnsprefixattribute?view=net-5.0) which is a hint to the designer to use this prefix when adding the XAML namespace to your XAML file.

```
[assembly: XmlnsPrefix("http://schemas.Mst2.com/2021", "mst2")]
```

Please note that this is respected by designers like in Visual Studio, but others might not.

> Identifies a recommended prefix to associate with a XAML namespace for XAML usage, when writing elements and attributes in a XAML file (serialization) or when interacting with a design environment that has XAML editing features.

> XAML processors or frameworks that incorporate XAML, or any process that performs XAML serialization, **should generally honor** the recommended prefix.

When consuming the namespace in your control (in a different assembly), it would look like this.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Mst2.View.Controls.Modules.TimerEntryControl"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mst2="http://schemas.Mst2.com/2021"
             xmlns:bcp="clr-namespace:ABitOfBinding"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <mst2:Mst2Dictionaries x:Key="Dictionaries" />
        <mst2:ByteBit2Bool x:Key="ByteBit2Bool" />
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis" />
        <mst2:TimerTimeAndRangeConverter x:Key="TimerTimeAndRangeConverter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <!-- user control contents here -->

</UserControl>
```

---

Another thing you could do is to create a resource dictionary for shared resources, e.g.:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:bcp="clr-namespace:ABitOfBinding"
                    xmlns:dc="clr-namespace:Mst2.Dictionaries"
                    xmlns:vc="clr-namespace:Mst2.ValueConverters">
   <dc:Mst2Dictionaries x:Key="Dictionaries" />
   <bcp:ByteBit2Bool x:Key="ByteBit2Bool" />
   <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis" />
   <vc:TimerTimeAndRangeConverter x:Key="TimerTimeAndRangeConverter"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then you can include it everywhere you need it without having to specify the namespace for each resource or redeclaring the resources each time.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Mst2.View.Controls.Modules.TimerEntryControl"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:bcp="clr-namespace:ABitOfBinding"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Mst2.ViewModel"
             xmlns:mw="clr-namespace:Mst2.View.Windows"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis" />
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="MySharedResources.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <!-- User control contents here -->

</UserControl>
```

If these are common resources you could also simply add them to the application resource dictionary, then they would be available in each control, without any further ado.